# Calculate bearing degrees in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate bearing degrees for a couple of coordinates using this formula:

```
=MOD(DEGREES(ATAN2(COS(RADIANS(latA))*SIN(RADIANS(latB))-SIN(RADIANS(latA))*COS(RADIANS(latB))*COS(RADIANS(lonB-lonA)),SIN(RADIANS(lonB-lonA))*COS(RADIANS(latB)))),360)
```

Set 1

```
LatA      LongA       LatB      LongB    
39.099912 -94.581213 38.627089 -90.200203
```

Set 2

```
LatA       LongA       LatB      LongB    
41.294253 -73.678856 41.293961 -73.678888
```

Set 3

```
LatA       LongA       LatB      LongB   
41.293721 -73.678911 41.293709 -73.678939
```

The bearing degrees calculator for set one is 96.51262423 which is correct.
Set 2 calculations is 184.7069985 which is correct.
Set 3 calculates 6.494672537 and is incorrect.

Why is my excel set 3 calculation not correct? The expected calculation should be about 230.

Comment: You need to add 360 degrees to that result to get `184.71`

Comment: Wrap the formula in `=MOD(...,360)` where the `...` is your formula without the `=`

Comment: No need to use `Named Range` since it considers entire Range rather than single cell,, so use cell reference. Or you may usey @ScottCraner idea using `Mod ,, 360`

Comment: Thanks. That fixed a few but not all coordinates. Question has been edited. Set three is not calculation properly.

Comment: if I paste your formula into a text editor, find'n'replace `latA` with the value you listed (repeating for the other 3 variables) and then paste that formula into excel, the formula returns `240.2991`. This is very close to an online calculator